# Slow boot due to SSD mounting?

Tags: mount, boot, ssd

Im seeing a weird problem, which i dont know where origins from.

im running Pop_OS! 20.10 and kernel 5.9.10

Running `sudo dmesg` i see:

```
[ 13.453986] rfkill: input handler enabled

[ 41.356512] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[ 41.470036] rfkill: input handler disabled

[ 42.042698] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[ 42.371273] usb 3-3.4: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
```

SDA1 is my SSD, it is not my boot drive, which a lot of the troubleshooting i can find appears to assume, it is simply a ext4 storage drive.

When running `systemd-analyze` i see a relatively high "firmware" time, which around the internet appears to be around 10x the normal time people get. My boot drive is a pcie 4 NVME drive.

`Startup finished in 15.478s (firmware) + 352ms (loader) + 3.989s (kernel) + 5.127s (userspace) = 24.948s`

Nothing too abnormal running `systemd-analyze blame` or `systemd-analyze critical-chanin` other than maybe upower taking 4 seconds to run before reaching graphical target.

Does anyone have an idea to something i could try?

It is not a super critical problem, but it is quite annoying to sit with a black screen after login for 25 seconds.

**Update**

`cat /etc/fstab` returns:

```
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=cff257f3-ddc3-4d67-8b47-b87c545a4a95 / ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
PARTUUID=5a670c7c-e69f-4578-9542-0ff8b8081789 /boot/efi vfat umask=0077 0 0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap none swap defaults 0 0
UUID=693161ff-c7ba-495d-8740-1c63cb6a2957 /home ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

`fsck` returns:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.36
```

Lastly to give an overview `lsblk` returns:

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    1 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sda1          8:1    1 931,5G  0 part  /media/username/SSD
sdb             8:16   1   3,6T  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   1 976,6G  0 part  /media/username/HDD1
└─sdb3          8:19   1   2,7T  0 part  /home
nvme0n1       259:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1   259:1    0 596,2G  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p3   259:2    0   331G  0 part  /
├─nvme0n1p4   259:3    0   603M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─nvme0n1p5   259:4    0   3,6G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap 253:0    0   3,6G  0 crypt [SWAP]
```

It looks a bit weird right now, i had another installation on nvme0n1p1 but i removed it, its my intention to move root on to it and expand, same with /home.

Comment: Your 25 sec is not too bad. Have you updated firmware, both UEFI & SSD? Not sure if any Ubuntu slow boot issues apply. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: 25 seconds is definitely too much considering it's an NVME device. Did you enable kernel automounting? Are you having this problem after a system update? Finally, can you add the contents of the /etc/fstab file and output of the fsck command?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with SSD's, as a boot system or not on several i7 bare systems. Example for boot SSD unit...delay of 30 seconds every boot sequence:

```
[ 1.894942] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:2124.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [SEM USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0

[ 1.896417] input: SEM USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/0003:1A2C:2124.0002/input/input4

[ 1.954771] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:2124.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [SEM USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input1

[ 32.656052] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[ 32.783076] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

I think it's related to SSD disk metadata, not raid. Reference system:

```
# uname -a

Linux JSCR64 4.9.0-14-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.246-2 (2020-12-17) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edited:
Just solved... tried to analize logs
Watching dmesg has a time lapse of about 30s on kernel.

```
[     2.067836] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:2188:0AE1.0003/input/input5
[    2.068070] hid-generic 0003:2188:0AE1.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[   32.609087] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   32.742762] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Watching daemon.log something wrong...
Jan  3 21:30:26 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Closed Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan  3 21:30:26 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sound Card.
Jan  3 21:30:26 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 112...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd-modules-load[386]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd-modules-load[386]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd-modules-load[386]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd-modules-load[386]: Inserted module 'coretemp'
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 keyboard-setup.sh[380]: cannot open file /tmp/tmpkbd.NEcSl2
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Flush Journal to Persistent Storage.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Set the console keyboard layout.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems.
....
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Reached target Sockets.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Load kernel modules needed to enable cpufreq scaling...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Speech Dispatcher...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Successfully called chroot.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Successfully limited resources.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Running.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Watchdog thread running.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 rtkit-daemon[625]: Canary thread running.
...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Login Service...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Restore /etc/resolv.conf if the system crashed before the ppp link was shut down.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 speech-dispatcher[626]: speech-dispatcher disabled; edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: anacron.timer: Adding 3min 49.607004s random time.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Speech Dispatcher.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 114) and group 'avahi' (GID 120).
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32 starting up.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Login Service.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 loadcpufreq[619]: Loading cpufreq kernel modules...libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1929 kmod_module_get_holders: could not open '/sys/module/mac80211/holders': No such file or directory
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Successfully called chroot().
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[665]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Failed to open /etc/resolv.conf: Invalid argument
...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 avahi-daemon[650]: Server startup complete. Host name is JSCR64.local. Local service cookie is 310164566.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 ModemManager[646]: <info>  ModemManager (version 1.6.4) starting in system bus...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Raise network interfaces.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.

Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 dbus[627]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'

Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 dbus[627]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan  3 21:31:53 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
...
Jan  3 21:31:55 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of lightdm.
Jan  3 21:31:55 JSCR64 systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 112...
```

Something wrong that lags stop of process UID=112. Who is this UID?

```
/etc# cat passwd|grep :112:
messagebus:x:108:112::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
lightdm:x:112:116:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
```

Something lags Stop of UID 112, we can disable to continue troubleshooting.
----------after disable lightdm we can see on booting new info.
Begin; Running /Scripts/local-block...done
|->Linux booting and taking a long time while looping with /scripts/local-block
Possible reason: Linux boot needs to know the UUID of the Swap file it tries to mount.
--- watching storage block devices...

```
/etc# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="bd746cd3-2b08-4b5c-93a6-dbeca9cb899f" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="735c261f-01"
```

--- It is not on system, only first partition, perhaps is a old swap partition before replacing rotational disks with SSD disks.

```
/etc# cd /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# ls
resume
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# cat resume
RESUME=UUID=43ea92db-85a7-4e73-9275-d033af4e9351
```

---- Another swap unit exists at past, that is not primary mounted as I see with blkid. Deactivate swap and remove resume file

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# swapoff --all
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# cat resume
RESUME=UUID=43ea92db-85a7-4e73-9275-d033af4e9351
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# rm resume
```

---- update initialization image

```
/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d# update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-14-amd64
```

--- after restart the problem is solved. :-)))